# Prettier formats in multiline for arrays and long line in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, prettier

When I use a long array and console, prettier formats it into multiple lines which is annoying in some cases. I want them break after a certain length. Can I set a breaking point for the prettier where it will make the new line? Please check the image.
[Prettier format demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiBMR.png)

Comment: You can add `// prettier-ignore` above a certain line to [disable Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#javascript) for that specific piece of code. You can also set a value for `printWidth`, although I don't think that will work as you want as long as you have operands like your example shows.

Comment: @hotpink yours should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 14):

Sadly can't be done, [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/352) you can find the discussion about the issue. The only apparently solution it's to add  a  comment `//` after the first array element:

Example:

```
imports: [
        BrowserModule, //
        FoodModule,
        SharedModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a fork of Prettier called [Prettier Now](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=remimarsal.prettier-now) that allows this.

After downloading, go into your `settings.json` and add ⤵︎

```json
"prettier.arrayExpand": true
```